# Spring 5 webclient with jetty connector continues to run after main completes execution

Tags: java, spring, jetty, webclient, spring-webflux

I am trying to test rest api by Spring 5 webclient with jetty connector. I am getting data from api call but main program continues to run even after main completes execution. How to resolve the issue.? What configuration needed so that Jetty connector stops after main completes its execution?

My connector initialization code:

```
SslContextFactory.Client sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory.Client();
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.setIdleTimeout(DefaultIdleTimeout);
ClientHttpConnector clientConnector = new JettyClientHttpConnector(httpClient, jettyResourceFactory);
webClient = WebClient.builder().baseUrl(getBaseUrl()).clientConnector(clientConnector).build();
```

Using webclient in main class :

```
webClient.get().uri("/getUri").exchange().flatMap(response.bodyToMono(String.class)).subscribe(di -> {
                    System.out.println(di);
                }, error -> {
                    System.out.println(error.getStackTrace());
                }, () -> {
                    System.out.println("Execution complete");
                });
```

getting below in log:

```
13:39:11.225 [HttpClient@1165b38-scheduler-1] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection - HttpConnectionOverHTTP@4eb423a5::DecryptedEndPoint@4345fb54{<hostname>/<targetIp>:443<->/<sourceIp>:65106,CLOSED,fill=-,flush=-,to=15016/15000} onFillInterestedFailed {}
13:39:11.225 [HttpClient@1165b38-scheduler-1] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector - Wakeup ManagedSelector@75ed9710{STARTED} id=1 keys=0 selected=0 updates=0
13:39:11.226 [HttpClient@1165b38-24] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector - Selector sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl@3d003adb woken with none selected
13:39:11.226 [HttpClient@1165b38-scheduler-1] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool - queue org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$DestroyEndPoint@74c9b13c startThread=0
13:39:11.226 [HttpClient@1165b38-24] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector - Selector sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl@3d003adb woken up from select, 0/0/0 selected
13:39:11.226 [HttpClient@1165b38-scheduler-1] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest - onClose FillInterest@52ac96eb{null}
13:39:11.226 [HttpClient@1165b38-21] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool - run org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$DestroyEndPoint@74c9b13c in QueuedThreadPool[HttpClient@1165b38]@45efc20d{STARTED,8<=8<=200,i=1,r=8,q=0}[ReservedThreadExecutor@4bef0fe3{s=2/8,p=0}]
13:39:11.226 [HttpClient@1165b38-scheduler-1] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpConnectionOverHTTP - Closed HttpConnectionOverHTTP@4eb423a5::DecryptedEndPoint@4345fb54{<hostname>/<targetIp>:443<->/<sourceIp>:65106,CLOSED,fill=-,flush=-,to=15017/15000}
13:39:11.226 [HttpClient@1165b38-24] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector - Selector sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl@3d003adb processing 0 keys, 0 updates
13:39:11.226 [HttpClient@1165b38-24] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector - updateable 0
13:39:11.226 [HttpClient@1165b38-24] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector - updates 0
13:39:11.226 [HttpClient@1165b38-24] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector - Selector sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl@3d003adb waiting with 0 keys
13:39:11.226 [HttpClient@1165b38-21] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector - Destroyed SocketChannelEndPoint@7a9db40c{<hostname>/<targetIp>:443<->/<sourceIp>:65106,CLOSED,fill=-,flush=-,to=0/15000}{io=0/0,kio=-1,kro=-1}->SslConnection@53046985{NEED_UNWRAP,eio=-1/-1,di=-1,fill=IDLE,flush=IDLE}~>DecryptedEndPoint@4345fb54{<hostname>/<targetIp>:443<->/<sourceIp>:65106,CLOSED,fill=-,flush=-,to=15017/15000}=>HttpConnectionOverHTTP@4eb423a5(l:/<sourceIp>:65106 <-> r:<hostname>/<targetIp>:443,closed=true)=>HttpChannelOverHTTP@7dafb76e(exchange=null)[send=HttpSenderOverHTTP@4491419(req=QUEUED,snd=COMPLETED,failure=null)[HttpGenerator@22805291{s=START}],recv=HttpReceiverOverHTTP@52385f05(rsp=IDLE,failure=null)[HttpParser{s=START,0 of -1}]]
13:39:11.227 [HttpClient@1165b38-21] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection - onClose HttpConnectionOverHTTP@4eb423a5::DecryptedEndPoint@4345fb54{<hostname>/<targetIp>:443<->/<sourceIp>:65106,CLOSED,fill=-,flush=-,to=15018/15000}
13:39:11.227 [HttpClient@1165b38-21] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection - onClose SslConnection@53046985::SocketChannelEndPoint@7a9db40c{<hostname>/<targetIp>:443<->/<sourceIp>:65106,CLOSED,fill=-,flush=-,to=0/15000}{io=0/0,kio=-1,kro=-1}->SslConnection@53046985{NEED_UNWRAP,eio=-1/-1,di=-1,fill=IDLE,flush=IDLE}~>DecryptedEndPoint@4345fb54{<hostname>/<targetIp>:443<->/<sourceIp>:65106,CLOSED,fill=-,flush=-,to=15018/15000}=>HttpConnectionOverHTTP@4eb423a5(l:/<sourceIp>:65106 <-> r:<hostname>/<targetIp>:443,closed=true)=>HttpChannelOverHTTP@7dafb76e(exchange=null)[send=HttpSenderOverHTTP@4491419(req=QUEUED,snd=COMPLETED,failure=null)[HttpGenerator@22805291{s=START}],recv=HttpReceiverOverHTTP@52385f05(rsp=IDLE,failure=null)[HttpParser{s=START,0 of -1}]]
13:39:11.227 [HttpClient@1165b38-21] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool - ran org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$DestroyEndPoint@74c9b13c in QueuedThreadPool[HttpClient@1165b38]@45efc20d{STARTED,8<=8<=200,i=1,r=8,q=0}[ReservedThreadExecutor@4bef0fe3{s=2/8,p=0}]
and continue to get log in console & program continues to run..................................
```

Comment: Going to need way more information than this. Can you post a [mcve], and state what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: If you are testing through Junits, use ```WebTestClient``` instead of WebClient

Comment: Here's a helpful link, for same https://www.callicoder.com/spring-5-reactive-webclient-webtestclient-examples/

Comment: @MichaelBerry updated query with example.

Comment: @AdityaRewari its useful but not helping me to resolve the issue. Thanks

Comment: So you have put webClient code in ```public static void main(String[] args)``` method 
...or in a Controller ?

Comment: @AdityaRewari in controller, and using CommandLineRunner in main.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the official docs

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-client-builder-jetty

> You can share resources between multiple instances of the Jetty client (and server) and ensure that the resources are shut down when the Spring ApplicationContext is closed by declaring a Spring-managed bean of type JettyResourceFactory

Your JettyHttpClientConnector should be instantiated with a jettyResourceFactory bean whose lifecycle should end as the test ends.